# How to remove rules from Rule Inspector on InfoPath 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, infopath

I see fields listed in the InfoPath 2013 Rule Inspector that I no longer have on the SharePoint list.  As a result it's causing a validation error when users try to submit the form.  Is there any way to remove the rules that are tied to fields that no longer exist (and are only visible on the Rule Inspector)?

Answer (score 0):

As is referred in this [post](https://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/11956/41881.aspx), you can remove the rules by modifying the source files of the InfoPath form (xsf) and deleting the related elements.

Some other posts that might be helpful:

[How can I delete a rule that shows in Rule Inspector, but does not show up in field rules?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e06e9d99-a287-4749-b233-2c5c71f7c79f/how-can-i-delete-a-rule-that-shows-in-rule-inspector-but-does-not-show-up-in-field-rules?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

[Modifying XSN Files (InfoPath).](https://sharepointkb.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/modifying-xsn-files-infopath/)